# Can't access rails post data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've spent the last couple of hours slowly losing my mind while trying to figure something out. I'm submitting a form in rails, everything works fine until I try to access the params. In the console I can see the following:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3mdEW2lHhkzpZbDsJCu8ZEV/wbq2YB/ztNR0RLTMZDs=", "utf8"=>"✓", "project"=>{"name"=>"woeij", "client"=>"iwej", "description"=>"oiejdoiew woeij"}, "id"=>"13"}
```

As you can see I'm sending name, client, description and id. I can access ID fine with something like:

```
@id = params[:id]
```

However, when I try to access name, client, or description in the same way they're all empty.
If I do:

```
@project = params[:project]
```

I get:

```
namewoeijclientiwejdescriptionoiejdoiew woeij
```

Would someone mind explaining what I'm doing wrong? And why I can't just get "woeij" when I do:

```
@name = params[:name]
```

Sorry for the stupid question, big thanks as always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attributes are nested, do

```
params[:project][:name]
```

to retrieve name.

A really cool tool in the rails console is the `y`: if you type `y params` they'll be presented really nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You have a hash inside a hash. After you do:

```
@project = params[:project]
```

You have all your project parameters inside that hash. You can select them like this:

```
@project[:name]   #=> "woeij"
@project[:client] #=> "iwej"
```

You can also select them in one go like this:

```
params[:project][:description] #=> "oiejdoiew woeij"
```